# Python Telegram bot get all jobs and their names?

Tags: python, telegram

Currently I have a bot where user a could create a subscription and remove it (through telegram's job queue). typical jobname would be its chat ID and a unique name given by the user. so for example, a user has 2 subscriptions ( 1: 154678Test 2: 154678Weekends). If the user wants to delete "Test", the bot could delete it using `context.job_queue.get_jobs_by_name(name="154678Test")` then remove it. I want to improve the bot by just making the user be given an option (through inline keyboard or so) what job is currently running (with his/her chat id 154678. My initial solution was to get all the job names and regex/filter them with the chat id,however when I come across the [Guide](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html). When I call `context.job_queue.jobs()` to get all the jobs currently in the bot, it returns a list of job objects and not its name (0x00016cda9928 etc instead of 154678Test ). I also tried using `context.job_queue.get_jobs_by_name(name="154678")` but it returns empty as it may match exactly.

Is there a way I can decode/get the name of the jobs via `context.job_queue.jobs()` or an option for
`context.job_queue.get_jobs_by_name` to have a regex option?

Answer (score 2):

context.job_queue.jobs() will return the **lists** of jobs with a hexcode of 0x00016cda9928 for example.
To obtain the name of each job names:

```
job_names = [job.name for job in context.job_queue.jobs()]
```

This list comprehension will return a list of job names (str). Example Result:

```
job_names = ['firstjob', 'secondjob' , 'thirdjob']
```

Comment: Hi @thekopiman, welcome to Stackoverflow! In the efforts to best assist you, it would be recommended to follow suggestions to produce a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to best aid with your question